# Customize ListView ContextMenu colors

Tags: android, layout

I need to change the colors and/or style of the ContextMenu when I long press an item of a ListView.

I've looked everywhere for an answer and cannot find anything related to ContextMenu customization.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContextMenu can not be customized. The only way is to make something that behaves similar. Try this [example](http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/07/custom-contextmenu-using-popupwindow.html).